# My Apple Dev account is about to expire. Will my provisioning profile(s) still allow me to test my applications on my iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios6

I have nothing in the App Store so I'm not worried about that. I am just wondering if I will still be able to develop new apps using Xcode and be able to test them out on an actual device if I have those profiles stored locally on disk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date is Feb 18th 2013 and I have been testing on all my devices since the day after posting this question.

Just in case, I went to the provisioning portal and created a new provisioning profile on January 25th 2013 which expires the same day in 2014.

So to answer the original question, YES you can test on your devices after your Developer Account passes the renewal date.

Answer (score 4):

No because if you look at your keychain youll see that your provisioning profile has an expiration date, a year from when you purchased the membership. You'll have to renew it to test on devices.

Comment: I thought they moved them all to 2079?

Comment: well i just know that when you build in xcode it checks the expiration date. for example, in keychain access i see that mine expires on 7/10/2013, so on that day until i renew i cannot test on devices.

Comment: I just made one right now being that my dev account expires in 2 days...
The expiration date on it is a year from today. I'm not sure if the expiration of my account overrides that or not...

Answer (score 0):

Your provisioning profile is basically a cryptographic certificate (not really, but understand it this way) that is signed by Apple which allows iOS to run your apps. The expiry date on the certificate is (as far as my knowledge is concerned) same as the expiry date on your Apple-Developer account.

So, **no**. You will not be able to test your apps after your account expires.